# Email Validation refined

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email, email-validation

I have following regex for email validation

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
```

only issue with this or similar solution available is that 123@domain.com passes this regex.

I do not want any email to start with a digit.

Comment: Your regex doesn't match all valid email addresses, but you seem to want that (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Why are you creating a regex for email validation? There are validators built into the browser and javascript libraries to do it for you.

Comment: The only really valuable email validation is to send an email with a validation link.  But I think the OP here is trying to further restrict emails.

Comment: using the reg ex provided

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0- 9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$    this was available on above link but   it again fails to take care of email starting with a digit

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z.!#$%&'+/=?^_{|}~-][a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_{|}~-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/; this one now works with most of the email, but still one issues remains it doesn;t check for domain ....it takes abc@com as valid email but instead it should check for abc@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@
```

This is the part of the regex that matches everything up to the `@` separator.    `0-9`. matches any digit.  So create a new phrase before that that *doesn't* match 0-9.  Then change the quantifier (currently `+`, at least 1) to `*` (0 or more) so that emails with only one character work (as long as it's not a number of course).

```
^[a-zA-Z.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-][a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-]*@
```

See https://regex101.com/r/qjdZ0A/1 for an interactive example.

Comment: var validRegex = /^[a-zA-Z.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-][a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/                     this one works for all    thanks

Comment: nope, that doesn't work on email addresses like `a@domain.com` because its one character before `@` can't match both the exactly-1 set and the at-least-1 set.  If you want to reject single character emails as well, then yours is correct.

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-][a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/; this one now works with most of the email, but still one issues remains it doesn;t check for domain  ....it takes abc@com as valid email but instead it should check for abc@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the expression of the email with a negative lookahead...

```
^(?![0-9])+[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
 _________
```

This only matches the email if the first character is NOT `0-9`

Comment: Why the `+` in `(?![0-9])+`? One or more identical negative lookaheads?

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z.!#$%&'+/=?^_{|}~-][a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_{|}~-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/; this one now works with most of the email, but still one issues remains it doesn;t check for domain ....it takes abc@com as valid email but instead it should check for abc@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

reg07 is what you need.

Code includes the process into building it

```
const stringToTest = "zaz234@microshit.kazo"

// Ideal
const regex = new RegExp('(^[^@.]+)@([^@.]+)\.{1}(\w{1,6}$)');
const reg = /(^(.+?))@(.+?).(\w{1,6})/;

const reg00 = /(^(.+)@)/;
const reg01 = /(^[^@]+)@/;
const reg02 = /(^[^@]+)@([^@]+)/;
const reg03 = /(^[^@]+)@([^@]+)\.{1}/;
const reg04 = /(^[^@]+)@([^@]+)\.{1}(\w+)/;
const reg05 = /(^[^@]+)@([^@]+)\.{1}(\w{2,4})/;
const reg06 = /(^[^@]+)@([^@]+)\.{1}(\w{1,6}$)/;
const reg07 = /(^[^@.]+)@([^@.]+)\.{1}(\w{1,6}$)/;

console.log(`We are testing this RexEx:\n${reg07}\n\nTo see if matches this string:\n${stringToTest}\n\nResults:`)
const booleanReg = reg07.test(stringToTest) 
const arrayReg = reg07.exec(stringToTest)

console.log(`1.Simeple Match:\n${booleanReg}\n2.Array Match:\n${arrayReg}`)
const emailInfo = {
  emailUserName: arrayReg[1],
  emailProvider: arrayReg[2],
  emailExtention: arrayReg[3]
}

console.log(`\n\nemail objet build:\n\n`, emailInfo)
```